# Update Only iPad app on app Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have an app on App-store, this app support both platform iPhone and iPad. i am updating my app few days ago, now my requirement is release new update only for iPad. Is this Possible? if Yes then How?

Answer (score 1):

**Sorry, you can't.**

- You can upgrade application scope like:

  iPhone only -> Universal

  iPad only   -> Universal
- You can't degrade application scope like :

  Universal -> iPhone only or iPad only